# How to initiate display of one view from another?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Assume you do not have a `UIController` to do the job. From inside the `UIView` .. how would you replace `self` with another `UIView`?

Comment: What language/toolkit are you using?

Comment: Sorry, objective-C. I will update description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another subview using `self.addSubview:` you may also want to check `self.bringSubviewToFront:`

For more information, check the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do from your question. UIController is not a class, for instance.

Ideally your app should be structured something like this:

#### `UIViewController` subclass

- Controls a set of objects that are all on screen at one time. For example, any number of `UITextFields`, `UIButtons`, `UIViews` and `UILabels`.
- has methods (IBActions and other delegate methods) which are triggered by user interaction with the controls and inputs.
- has IBOutlets which allow it to manipulate what the user sees on screen. For instance an IBOutlet attached to a `UILabel` allows changing the text when a user presses a button.

`UIView` is only generally subclassed if you need custom drawing code, or some kind of custom control. Don't put application logic here if you can help it, and you can usually help it.

You can have multiple `UIViewController`s but they usually function very independently. Often View Controllers don't maintain references for other view controllers. If they do it's loose couplings like the delegate pattern.

Bottom line: if you have two views controllers that need to communicate with each-other, you need to have a reference to one from the other. This usually occurs in the form of a property on one or both of the view controllers, and is connected either by interface builder or at run time when you create them.